# for what a does h have an extreme point in (1,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I got this function:

$h(x, y) = (x − 1)^2 + 2a(x − 1)y + y^2 + y^4$

For what $a$ does h have either a maxima- or a minima-point but not a saddle point in (1,0)?

I have confirmed that the point is stationary, but it gets really tricky when trying to use the Quadratic form when having $a$ around. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hessian matrix of $h$ at $(1,0)$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&2a\\2a&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, whose trace is $4$ and whose determinant is $4-4a^2$. If $\lvert a\rvert>1$, then $h$ will have then a saddle point at $(1,0)$. If $\lvert a\rvert<1$, $h$ will have a minimum at $(1,0)$. And if $a=\pm1$, then$$h(x,y)=\bigl((x-1)\pm y\bigr)^2+y^4.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I have found that we have a minima point at (1,0) when a=1, but when a= -1 I get a positive semidefinite response when checking the quadratic form of the second derivatives. Do you have any idea of how to continue investigating this point?

Comment: In both cases, since $h(x,y)$ is always non-negative and since $h(1,0)=0$, $h$ has a minimum at $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

- $h_x=2(x-1)+2ay\implies h_x(1,0)=0$
- $h_y=2a(x-1)+2y+4y^3\implies h_y(1,0)=0$

then $(1,0)$ is a stationary point as you have noticed.

Then we need to consider

- $h_{xx}=2\implies h_x(1,0)=2$
- $h_{yy}=2+12y^2\implies h_y(1,0)=2$
- $h_{xy}=h_{yx}=2a\implies h_y(1,0)=2a$

finally proceed by the [**hessian matrix test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye